# Plotting scatter graph with marginal histograms with Python seaborn 0.7

Tags: python, scatter-plot, seaborn

I have some python code that plotted a scatter graph with marginal histograms. This worked fine with seaborn 0.5 and still does work if I go back to this version. However, I'd like to get it to work with 0.7!

I don't use python often and mainly only use scripts set up by others that I adjust slightly.

The problem appears to be happening in the following line:

```
sns.lmplot(x='Moisture Content (%)', y='Dry Density (kg/m3)', hue='Test',
           data=data, ax=ax_joint, fit_reg=False, legend=False, palette=test_colours)
```

ax is no longer recognised in seaborn 0.7.

```
TypeError: lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax'
```

The output still gives me completed marginal histograms but the scatter graph is blank.

If you need more info then please let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Why are you using `lmplot` to draw a scatter graph with marginal histograms? That's not the right function.

Answer (score 0):

`seaborn lmplot ax` will show you that `lmplot` returns you a `figure-level` instead of `axes-level`. So in order to manage `lmplot` use `FacetGrid`.

`FacetGrid` will plot on different variables that you states in different graphs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="smoker")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill")
```

[FacetGrid result image](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/seaborn-FacetGrid-2.png)

You can imagine doing a `groupby` on the dataframe which gives you the different graphs.

Refer to [this](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) for more example on plotting `lmplot`